# LDP Indirect Container

Tags: rest, rdf, linked-data, linked-data-platform

I have the read [LDP Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/ldp), I can understand the use of Basic Container and Direct Container but not that of Indirect Container, I understand how it works but cannot figure out a use-case in a real life scenario. Can someone provide such a real-life scenario to explain the usefulness of Indirect Containers

Answer (score 0):

[LDP Primer](https://www.w3.org/2012/ldp/hg/ldp-primer/ldp-primer.html#intro) is far better for understanding the general use-case. The practical difference is that a direct container (DC) can only contain links to its member resources (like *Golf club* DC may contain *Membership card* resources, while it would be unreasonable to contain *Person* resources, as people are not owned by the club).